# Which framework to use: CodeIgniter, Symfony or CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, codeigniter, symfony1

I would like to use one of the framework listed in the title but I am afraid to choose the wrong one since I don't know much about the framework. I know PHP well, but every time I create a site I spent too much time creating my own little framework . Matter of fact, I was afraid of using a framework because of fear of being stuck with inflexible and slow framework that couldn't handle high traffic website.

Which framework addresses my fear the most?

Comment: A very subjective questions without criteria. If you want something easy to learn as a first step, use Cake or CI.

Answer (score 7):

> Matter of fact, I was afraid of using a framework because of fear of being stuck with inflexible and slow framework that couldn't handle high traffic website.

CodeIgniter is the most flexible framework of the bunch you have mentioned. It's also the fastest. There are [more than a few benchmarks](http://www.alrond.com/en/2007/jan/25/performance-test-of-6-leading-frameworks/) confirming this.

Symphony and Cake are both Rails-esque frameworks that (in my view) will force you to adopt their conventions. CodeIgniter doesn't. You can be extremely liberal in choosing what features you want, and how you want to use the framework. It is also very easy to extend and change core functionality without modification.

Comment: Man that page is from 2007...and it doesn't take into account CakePhp, nor Zend, nor any other (imho) interesenting competitor like Kohana

Comment: I would be skeptical about a four year old benchmark.

Comment: @Klaus: That's the first one I found, you're welcome to search for more.

Answer (score 3):

Symfony has a good reputation, after that comes CakePHP. I don't know about CodeIgniter.

edit: here is a comparison in french (sorry)

http://www.mti.epita.fr/blogs/2010/06/17/symfony-vs-codeigniter/

The conclusion says CodeIgniter is good for small project, and Symfony is recommended if you have a bigger project to do (more than a month to dev).